# relationship between matrix and adjoint of a matrix and orthonormal system

Tags: matrices, orthonormal, adjoint-operators

The problem is:
Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^*A=I$, the $n\times n$ identity matrix ($A^*$ is the adjoint), then the columns $g_1,\cdots,g_n$ in $A$ constitute an orthonormal system in $\mathbb{C}^m$.

What the adjoint of $A$ is? And how could this be true in $\mathbb{C}^m$? And by the way, I want to know what's the relationship, or connection between the columns and rows of $A$? Cause this is a knowledge for the frame analysis, I especially want to know what is $<A_k,A_k>$? (The dot product between the same **row** of $A$.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The adjoint of $A$ is $A^*=\overline{A}^T$, the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_convention)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A^*A=I$. On both sides of this equation is an $n\times n$ matrix. We can understand what this equation means, by writing down what it means for the $(i,j)$th component on both sides:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \overline{A}_{ki}A_{kj}=\delta^i_j$$

where $\delta^i_j$ is the Kronecker delta, which is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise, and $A_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$th component of the matrix $A$, i.e. the number at row $i$, column $j$.

The columns of $A$ are the vectors $g_j=(A_{ij})_{i=1,..,m}\in\mathbb{C}^m$ for $j=1,..,n$. The above equation can be rewritten using the scalar product in $\mathbb{C}^m$:

$$\langle g_i, g_j\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^m \overline{A}_{ki}A_{kj} = \delta^i_j$$

where $\langle v,w\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^m \overline{v}_k w_k$ for $v,w\in\mathbb{C}^m$. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is called the *scalar product*. This means *by definition* that $(g_n)_n$ is an orthonormal system of $\mathbb{C}^m$:
$$\|g_i\|^2=\langle g_i, g_i\rangle=1\,\,\text{and}\,\,\langle g_i,g_j\rangle=0\,\,\text{for}\,\,i\not=j$$

That is, all the column vectors have norm $1$ and are orthogonal to one another.

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, such matrices are called *unitary*, or *orthogonal* if all the elements are real.